# How can I get different environment values according to different OS in one premake5.lua?

Tags: premake

In my project, I want to get different environment value according to different OS, just like get A from Windows and get B from Linux, I try to use filter function like the code shown below:

`filter {"system:windows"}
   local value = os.getenv("A")
filter {"system:linux"}
   local value = os.getenv("B")`

or use configuration like that:

`configuration {"windows"}
    local value = os.getenv("A")
configuration {"linux"}
    local value = os.getenv("B")`

When I run the premake5.lua, it will return an error: **attempt to concatenate a nil value**.

Is there anything I misunderstand? How can I implement it correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option:

```
if os.is("windows") then
  ...
else if os.is("macosx") then
  ...
else if os.is("linux") then
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [os.get](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/wiki/os.get) to determine which platform you are currently running on.

```
if os.get() == "windows" then
...
end
```